# DotNetOpenAuth - OpenId login to Google asks for confirmation every time

Tags: c#-4.0, openid, dotnetopenauth

I'm using DotNetOpenAuth to login to my site using Google OpenId. Simple code, discussed many times before:

```
protected static readonly string ENDPOINT = "https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id";

public void RequestAuthentication(string realm, Uri returnUrl) {
    using (OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty()) {
        IAuthenticationRequest openRequest = openid.CreateRequest(ENDPOINT, realm, returnUrl);
        var fr = new FetchRequest();
        fr.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email, true));
        fr.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Preferences.TimeZone, false));
        fr.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Name.FullName, true));
        fr.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Alias, false));
        fr.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Name.Last, true));
        fr.Attributes.Add(new AttributeRequest(WellKnownAttributes.Name.First, true));
        openRequest.AddExtension(fr);
        openRequest.RedirectToProvider();
    }
}
```

This works, but every time Google asks confirmation to pass users' email to my web site, ignoring 'Remember my decision' checkbox!

I already tried to replace FetchRequest with ClaimsRequest (with AXFetchAsSregTransform) - no difference.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Glad you solved it. Just one tip: by `using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Extensions.AttributeExchange`, you can simplify each of your attribute lines to this: `fr.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems this is Google-side problem.

In my Google account under 'Безопасность' > 'Авторизация приложений и сайтов'  ('Security' > 'Authorized sites and apps' ?) settings I removed my site's tokens (all repeating items), on next logon I again checked 'remember' on confirmation page and viola - all future logon to my site does not require confirmation.